# Two portions of HtmlUnit can't co-exist together

Tags: css, dom, groovy, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit in a Groovy script to parse web pages. I want to be able to retrieve the final style of each element, as well.  This is a test script that iterates through the entire page and dumps the elements and attributes and, hopefully, the styles.

After some digging, I found http://old.nabble.com/Access-to-element-coputed-style-td24654513.html, which caused me to discover that the basic htmlunit Grab call did not include the class he referred to: `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration`.

But I did find information about `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration` at http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/hudson/htmlunit/2.2-hudson-9/htmlunit-2.2-hudson-9.jar!/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/javascript/host/ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.class?classDetails=ok.

I used the Ivy information at the top of that page to construct the Grab statement I needed.  However, these two entries seem to conflict with each other.  Here is my code:

```
@Grab('org.jvnet.hudson:htmlunit:2.2-hudson-9')
@Grab('net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.10')

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.*

RefreshHandler rh = new RefreshHandler() {
    void handleRefresh( final Page page, final URL url, final int seconds ) {}
}

client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10)
client.setRefreshHandler(rh)

client.javaScriptEnabled = false
client.appletEnabled = false
client.cssEnabled = true
page = client.getPage('http://www.google.com/')
parseChildren(page.documentElement)

def parseChildren(node) {
    println "open ${node.nodeName}"
    node.attributes.each { attr ->
        println "   ${attr.key}/${attr.value.name} = ${attr.value.value}"
    }
    //ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration style = ((HTMLElement)node.getScriptObject()).jsxGet_currentStyle()
    //println "       style: ${style.dump()}"
    node.childElements.each { child ->
        parseChildren(child)
    }
    println "close ${node.nodeName}"
}
```

If I run the Grab statements in the order shown above, the script runs perfectly but without the style information.  However, if I try to uncomment the two lines related to CSS styles, I get this error:

> Caught: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.HTMLElement overrides final method jsxGet_tagName.()Ljava/lang/String;
>   java.lang.VerifyError: class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.HTMLElement overrides final method jsxGet_tagName.()Ljava/lang/String;

On the other hand, if I reverse the order of the two Grab statements, I get this exception:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FIREFOX_10 for class: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FIREFOX_10 for class: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
>     at testHtmlUnit.run(testHtmlUnit.groovy:13)

There's obviously some kind of interaction between these two.  It seems like the hudson jar contains a full but old implementation of HtmlUnit that overrides the current 2.10 version when it comes last.  But when it comes first, as shown above, it seems like HTMLElement is conflicting with something in the JavaScript implementation code.

The bottom line is that I want to add the ability to retrieve CSS styles from HtmlUnit.  If this is the right way, I need to make these jars work nicely together.  If this is the wrong way to go about getting those styles, I'd appreciate help on how to accomplish it.  Either way, thanks!